# CKEditor not showing after enable clean url in drupal 7

Tags: wysiwyg, uri

I am facing some problem with ckeditor. It works perfect when clean url option is disabled, but after enable it only getting textarea. One more thing I have noticed that it is showing again after deleting all the content from textarea and saved it.

I have some other module installed.
WYSIWYG Filter - enabled, IMCE - enabled, CKEditor - enabled, IMCE Wysiwyg API bridge - disabled, jquery update - enabled, Wysiwyg - disabled